# (start, end) vs. (start, length) in API design

Tags: language-agnostic, api-design

I've seen two alternative conventions used when specifying a range of indexes, e.g.

```
subString(int startIndex, int length);
```

vs.

```
subString(int startIndex, int endIndex);
```

They are obviously equivalent in terms of what you can do with them, the only difference being whether you specify the ending index or the length of the range.

I'm assuming that in all cases `startIndex` would be inclusive, and `endIndex` exclusive.

Are there any compelling reasons to prefer one over the other when defining an API?

Comment: By the way, I think it is better to use firstIndex/lastIndex -- with start/end indexes it is open question whether element at endIndex is included or not so one have to dig into doc.

Answer (score 7):

I'd prefer the `length` one simply because it gives me one less question to ask/look up in the documentation.

For the `endIndex` based one - is that an inclusive or exclusive end point?

(For either variant, the same question *could* be asked about `startIndex`, but it would be a perverse API that makes it exclusive).

Answer (score 3):

How to disambiguate positional arguments...

1. use longer names subStringFromUpto( startIndex , stopIndex )
2. use uniform convention across the whole library

Didn't we find better after all these years ?

Ah yes, in Smalltalk maybe, since the question is tagged language-agnostic...

```
aString copyFrom: startIndex to: stopIndex.
aString substringOfLength: length startingAt: startIndex.
```

Less ambiguity, but maybe we'll have to wait another 30 years before larger adoption of such style
(it probably looks too much simple to be serious)

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question and I think the preference for which to use comes down to what are the most common use cases. Most use cases are equally simple using either API, but consider this one:

You want to get a substring that starts at 5 and ends at the end of the string. Using the index based version (assuming it's second index is exclusive), it's as simple as:

```
str.subString(5, str.length());
```

With the length based API:

```
str.subString(5, str.length() - 5);
```

That second approach is much less succinct and obvious. However, this can be solved by simply stating that if the length will cause an overflow of the remaining string, it will gracefully support that (e.g. `str.subString(5, str.length());` would grab everything from index 5 to the end even though it may be asking for more characters than are left). Ruby does this with their [String#splice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-slice) method in addition to supporting advanced things like negative indices.

In my opinion, the index based approach is more concrete, especially when negative indices aren't allowed. This makes it very obvious what to expect from the API, which can be a good thing; making it harder to shoot yourself in the foot. However, a well documented API, like Ruby, makes it easy to empower the programmer and can make for some graceful substring-ing.

I also find that in general, when I'm performing substring operations, that I often know my beginning and end points. With the length based approach, that's going to require an additional calculation when calling the API (e.g. `substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)`).

Answer (score 1):

Someone should do a study of typical call sites to find out which approach yields more succinct code (and therefore probably correct code).

I like the argument that using 'length' you don't have to look at the documentation, but you may already be looking at the documentation to determine whether the 2nd integer is the 'end' or the 'length'.  If you name it endExclusive, then it's just as self-documenting.